# How to place values from struct to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to do it like bellow, but for next operations i would like to output an array that consist of 3-5 structs. 
I would like to do it like : `string[] my_array = {struct1,struct2,struct3};` but don't know how to do it correct.

```
 public struct student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
class H
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student student_info = new student();
        student_info.Name = "Mike";
        student_info.Last_Name = "Johnson";
        student_info.Birthday = new DateTime(1983, 12, 03);
        student_info.Address = "Baker str. 84/4a";
        student_info.City = "New LM";
        student_info.Zip = 90541;
        student_info.Country = "Paris";

       string[] my_array = { student_info.Name, student_info.Last_Name, student_info.Birthday.ToString(), student_info.Address, student_info.City, student_info.Zip.ToString(), student_info.Country };

       for (int counter = 0; counter < my_array.Length; counter++)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(my_array[counter]);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you really know the difference between `struct` and `class` in C#, you should default to using `class`. If you are not sure how many objects, use a `new List<student>` and `.Add` your `new student` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of the struct.

```
student[] my_array = new student[] {struct1,struct2,struct3};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you're doing. But here's my best guess.

If the objects will all be of the same struct, you can just use that.

```
student[] args = new [] { struct1, struct2, struct3 };
```

If they aren't the same type, the greatest common denominator between three structs like this will be `object`. So,

```
object[] args = new object[] { struct1, struct2, struct3 };
```

If you'd like, on the other hand, to combine the three structs into a single string array as you've shown us, that's a little different, and I can show you if you confirm that that is actually what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I want to combine few structs into one array.